YARP RemoteCertificateNameMismatch when using set-up certificate with request
I implemented a small application that only hosts kestrel with yarp. It should work as an API-Gateway.
I set up Kestrel with the certificate that all my applications use like this:
    builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(commandlineArguments);
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>
        {
            httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = baseCertificate;
        });
    });

baseCertificate is a X509Certificate2 instance, loaded from the windows cert-store.
I set up Yarp like this:
    // YARP
    builder.Services
    .AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("yarp"))
    .ConfigureHttpClient((context, handler) =>
    {
        handler.SslOptions.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection
        {
            baseCertificate
        };
    });

So I'm using the same certificate there.
When executing the applications and have my services communicate through the YARP instance (the configurations for the forwarding are set up in the config-file), I encounter a RemoteCertificateNameMismatch policy error!
I changed the YARP set-up to this:
    // YARP
    builder.Services
        .AddReverseProxy()
        .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("yarp"))
        .ConfigureHttpClient((context, handler) =>
        {
            handler.SslOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback =
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                if(policyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
                {
                    if (certificate == null)
                        return false;

                    // THESE HashStrings have the same value! So in this case I accept it as valid.
                    return certificate.GetCertHashString() == baseCertificateHashString;
                }

                return true;
            });

            handler.SslOptions.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection
            {
                baseCertificate
            };
        });

And now the request is accepted. But I do not think it must or should even be that way.
When debugging into the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback, I noticed that under the instance of the sender-object, there is a property called TargetHostName, that is set to "localhost". Is that the name that is meant? Of course "localhost" is not part of the certificates SANs. How do I solve this?
Below is an examplatory configuration file that is used by yarp.
    {
  "Urls": "https://myHostName:1234",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
      "Yarp": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "yarp": {
    "routes": {
      "service_infrastructure": {
        "clusterId": "cluster_infrastructure",
        "match": {
          "path": "infrastructure/{**catch-all}"
        }
      },
      "service_UserMgmt_UserFrontend": {
        "clusterId": "cluster_UserMgmt_UserFrontend",
        "match": {
          "path": "usermgmt/userfrontend/{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "clusters": {
      "cluster_infrastructure": {
        "destinations": {
          "destination1": {
            "address": "https://localhost:50781"
          }
        }
      },
      "cluster_UserMgmt_UserFrontend": {
        "destinations": {
          "destination1": {
            "address": "https://localhost:50792"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


As my config shows the forwarding was done to "localhost" and that was wrong since it was not part of the certificate SAN's.
The FQDN of the device needed to be used for the forwarding of course.
I did not think that I could use the FQDN in the first place, because frankly, I suggest a software that accepts calls from outside the device, will not call itself with its own name. Instead, I expected that I have to use "localhost" so that the infrastructure knows it just has to route the communication to another port on the same device.
